# Solving $x^2 \equiv 89 \pmod{121}$

Tags: number-theory

Each modulus is of the form $p^2$ for a prime $p$; you should first solve them for $x_1$ modulo $p$ and then solve for $y$ such that $x_2 = x_1 + py$ is a solution modulo $p^2$.

$$x^2 \equiv 89 \pmod{121}$$

Not sure what it means by $x_1$ modulo $p$

Comment: They want you to first solve $x_1 \equiv 89 \pmod(11)$ and then, find $x_2 \equiv 89 \pmod(121)$ for $x_2=x_1+py$ for some y.

Comment: So does  $x_1=1$?

Comment: This can be attacked with Hansel's Lemma. Have you already studied that?

Comment: Yes but the question told me to use the method i posted

Comment: @Tony No, $x_1$ does $\pm 1$.

Comment: So we need to solve $x_1^2=89 \pmod {11}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $121=11^2$, as a first step we try to solve $x^2\equiv 89 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$.  This has two solutions, $x=\pm 1$.  Next, we try to lift the solution mod 11 to a solution mod 121. We will have two cases, depending on which of the two solutions we try to lift.  We will consider just one below, with the other being similar.

Suppose that $x=1+11k$ and $x^2\equiv 89 \pmod{121}$.  Expanding, $1+22k\equiv 89 \pmod{121}$, so $k\equiv 4$, hence $x\equiv 45 \pmod{121}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $x^2-89=(x+1)(x-1)$ over $\mathbb{F}_{11}$. Henve $x=\pm 1$ is a solution modulo $11$. Now try $x_2=\pm 1 +11y$, e.g., $x_2=1+44$.