# Solve $x^2 \equiv 439 \pmod {529}$

Tags: number-theory

Solve $x^2 \equiv 439 \pmod {529}$

I know $529=23^2$

I have $x_1^2 \equiv 439 =2 \pmod{23} \implies x_1= ±\sqrt{2} \mod(23)$ but this seems wrong to me.
Then $x_2= ±\sqrt{2} +23y$...

Comment: $a^2\equiv b^2 mod(c)$ does not imly $a\equiv b mod(c)$

Comment: This is the same question as [before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694209/solving-x2-equiv-89-pmod121). Note that you need an integer $\bmod 23$, not $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I managed to do the others but with this one I get $\sqrt(2)$ which is a problem

Comment: $2\equiv 25$ (mod 23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that we have
$$
x^2-439=(x + 5)(x - 5) 
$$
in $\mathbb{F}_{23}$. Hence $x=\pm 5$ solve the congruence $x^2\equiv 439\bmod 23$.
Now proceed as [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694209/solving-x2-equiv-89-pmod121).